# My simple rebus

Tags: rebus

I liked the idea of a rebus puzzle, so I've taken a crack at making a simple one!

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are:

> The apple of my eye.

Because, simply,

> The apple is in an/my eye.

Comment: Who took a bite out of the apple of your eye, though? That seems cruel and unusual :-) Jamal Senjaya's answer might have a clue...

Comment: @Phylyp the apple with a bite is also an [Apple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.).

Comment: That's what I was alluding to @ibrahimmahrir by referring to Jamal's answer, which I felt (at that time) was the correct one!

Answer (score 11):

You are:

> iMac

Because

> inside the eye (I), there is an apple logo.

Answer (score 11):

My thought

> Steve Jobs

Because

> **Apple vision**ary

Comment: haha, this is really creative! I love it!

Answer (score 11):

You could be:

> Apple Watch

Because:

> Watch can mean "to observe" or "timepiece worn on the wrist".